# Permission problem when building docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I currently have one Jenkins server that build a Docker image, save it (docker save) and send it over ssh to a second server.

In the second server i am loading the image (docker load) and run a container of that image (with an apache server).

When i am checking the result on the browser i got a "Permission denied".

I can see that the problem is causing because i am building the image with Jenkins (ausing a "jenkins" user).

When I am doing the same steps with Jenkins (but building the image manually with the jenkins user on the server) everything is working.

Do you have an idea why when building with the Jenkins tool using the jenkins user I have permission problems in my container ?

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile to the question.

Comment: Did you try the docker steps with sudo?